# Oracle-UCM service CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL is throwing errors when trying to checkin an existing file

Tags: java, web-services, oracle-ucm

I'm working on Java code that checks whether a file exists in the system and whether it's checked out. After these checks it calls the CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL service. This is where it stops. Checking in a new file works just fine, but it's the checking in of an existing file that's giving errors.

The specific error displayed (without making modifications to my original code) is !cscheckinitemexists. A bunch of googling turned up the solution to clear the data binder, yet then it comes up with the error that it cannot retrieve or use the security token.

Here's the code I use to clear and retrieve the data binder:

```
m_binder.clearResultSets();
m_binder.getLocalData().clear();
m_binder.setEnvironment(new IdcProperties(SharedObjects.getSecureEnvironment()));
```

Answer (score 0):

What does the rest of your code look like? You can link to a Gist.

Generally, I have run into this due to data pollution (as you stated).

Is there a reason you are using m_binder instead of creating a brand new DataBinder?

After looking at your gist, you are using m_binder (the DataBinder from the service) to execute CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL. Don't do this. Use a separate DataBinder (as you did for the DOC_INFO_BY_NAME service call).

Either use requestBinder or a new DataBinder.

Comment: Here's a gist of my code: https://gist.github.com/Naktsvilks/b86e9bdb554ae129ee88

I've tried both a new DataBinder and m_binder, still the same error

Answer (score 0):

Another way to avoid this issue is to simply not look for the checkout.  CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL supports a flag that checks out a content item if it's not already checked out.

Add the flag "isForceCheckout" to your binder, with a value of "1".